# Sql server how to avoid getting outer block to run first in the store procedure

Tags: sql-server

How do I prevent this error

> "OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server returned message
>   "[Teradata][ODBC Teradata Driver][Teradata Database] Object
>   'teradataDB.tablename' does not exist."

I use openquery to check if the teradata table exists, if exists, drop the table and recreate the table from select.  And I use openquery to insert the data from the teradata table to a sql server table.
However, when I run the store procedure, it gives me the above error because it executes the insert and select at the last two lines first. How do I modify it to run the first block first and then the last two lines?

```
DECLARE @strSql NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''
DECLARE @TableName NVARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @linkedServer NVARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @TabExists BIT

DECLARE TableCursor CURSOR LOCAL FOR
SELECT TABLENAME FROM #TableList

OPEN TableCursor
FETCH NEXT FROM TableCursor INTO @TableName

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
BEGIN
SET @strSql='Select count(1) as TabExists FROM DBC.TABLES WHERE  TABLEKIND=''T'' AND DATABASENAME=''teradataDB'' AND TABLENAME=''' +@TableName+ ''''
SET @strSql = N'select @TabExists=TabExists from OPENQUERY('+@linkedServer+', ''' + REPLACE(@strSql, '''', '''''') + ''')'
EXEC sp_executesql @strSql, N'@TabExists BIT OUT', @TabExists OUT;


FETCH NEXT FROM TableCursor INTO @TableName  

IF (@TableName ='tablename')
BEGIN
    IF (@TableName ='tablename') AND (@TabExists = 1)
    BEGIN
        EXEC sp_executesql
        N'
        EXEC (
            ''DROP TABLE teradataDB.tablename'') AT [linkedserver];'
    END

    EXEC sp_executesql
    N'
    EXEC (
        ''CREATE TABLE AS SELECT (
                      ~~~~
                    ) 
        '' ) AT [linkedserver];'


END

END
CLOSE TableCursor
DEALLOCATE TableCursor

INSERT INTO sqlServerDB.tablename
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY (linkedserver, 'SELECT columns FROM teradataDB.tablename')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of above code with `CURSOR`, you can use following code for the same.

```
IF (EXISTS (SELECT * 
                 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
                 WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'TheSchema' 
                 AND  TABLE_NAME = 'TheTable'))
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE teradataDB.tablename
END
```

Now you don't need to create the structure of table, and fire the following query.

```
INSERT INTO sqlServerDB.tablename
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY (linkedserver, 'SELECT columns FROM teradataDB.tablename')
```